# ¿Porqué no me quiere reconocer el operador "*" para multiplicar un double con un float?

Tags: java, java-8

**Me aparece como mensaje a la hora de ejecutar:**

Main.java:16: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
Areacir = (pi*(C*C));
^
1 error

**Mi Código**

````
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 class URI{
    public static void main(String ars[]){
        float A, B, C,Areatri, Areacir, Areatrape, Areacuadra, Arearecta;
        double pi=3.14159;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
        A = key.nextFloat();
        B = key.nextFloat();
        C = key.nextFloat();
        /*Area del triangulo*/ 
        Areatri = A*C/2;
        System.out.println("TRIANGULO: "+df.format(Areatri));
        /*Area circulo*/ 
        Areacir = pi*(C*C);
        System.out.println("TRIANGULO: "+df.format(Areacir));
        /* El área del trapecio */ 
        Areatrape= ((A+B)*C)/2;
        System.out.println("TRIANGULO: "+df.format(Areatrape));
        /*Area del cuadrado*/ 
        Areacuadra= B*B;
        System.out.println("TRIANGULO: "+df.format(Areacuadra));
        /*Area del rectangulo*/ 
        Arearecta= A*B;
        System.out.println("TRIANGULO: "+df.format(Arearecta));
    }
}```
````

Comment: Probá de declarar pi como float en lugar de double.

Answer (score 2):

En Java float y double no son intercambiables. Si bien ambos representan números con decimales, son diferentes. Uno ocupa 32 bits y el otro 64. Puedes convertir de uno al otro por medio de typecast:

```
float n = 1.23f
double n2 = (double)n;
float n3 = (float)n2;
```

También puedes hacer la conversión a partir de clases envolventes como Float y Double. En general, estos tipos proveen varios constructores y admiten la asignación a partir de tipos primitivos. Al menos en el caso de los tipos envolventes numéricos, todos brindan las funciones `byteValue(), shortValue(), intValue(), longValue(), floatValue() y doubleValue()`. Algunos ejemplos de conversiones:

```
double n = 0.518;
Double n2 = n;
Float n3 = new Float(n);
float n4 = n.floatValue();
Double n5 = Double.valueOf(n);
Float n6 = (Float)n4; // El typecast es válido, pero innecesario en este caso
double n7 = n2;
```

Las formas mostradas son intercambiables, pero pueden tener comportamientos diferentes. Por algo es que son funciones diferentes aunque aparenten ser lo mismo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! pude resolver el problema :)